# Wordpress malware Eclkspsa

Tags: php, wordpress, malware

I've got a problem with a website using wordpress. Seems like after a bunch of updates (may be not) it was infected by Eclkspsa.

I'm not able to find where this script comes from on the site pages:

```
<script data-cfasync='false' type='text/javascript' src='//tags1.eclkspsa.com/adServe/banners?tid=100486_270041_0&tagid=2'></script>
```

Searching through database and ftp for "eclkspsa" didn't help.

Over the internet i've found an [article](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/malvertising-eclkspsa) that was created about a year ago, but i have no Sweet Captcha plugin.

Right now i'm trying to find how the sript come to the page (searching trough hook to wordpress functions e.t.c.), but it's going to take tons of time to recognize it from this amount of hooks.

Do someone already met this problem or have any ideas how to find it faster?